# Subclipse checking out as folder not Java project

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I'm trying to import a Java project from my teams subversion repository. So I go through the import GUI for subversion, select my repository and the project, then choose to check it out as a project into the workspace.

[image]

However, the project now appears in my workspace simply as a folder:

[image]

Trying to add a new class tells me "source folder is not a java project". Is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out as a project only does what you want if you have checked-in the Eclipse .project, .classpath files etc.  In that scenario those files get checked out and configure the Eclipse project.  Otherwise you are just getting an Eclipse "Simple Project" which does not have the Java tools configured.

I assume you do not have those Eclipse files in your repository, so you want to use the other option that lets you run the Eclipse Create Project wizard as part of the checkout.  This lets you choose the project type and setup some of the configuration.  You can skip most of the configuration since you can also do that after the checkout finishes if you prefer.

See: [Subclipse Checkout Documentation](http://help.collab.net/topic/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/checkout.html)